# Is there a way to get the value of number of epochs (nb_epochs) in each iteration?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I would like to design a new regularizer, for which I need the value of the current epoch during training.

For example with

```
Epoch 7/10
0s - loss: 93.5298 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 98.3877 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
0s - loss: 91.8406 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 96.8459 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

I would like to get the value of 7 and 8 during training.

How can this be done in keras?

Answer (score 3):

The regularizer is tricky in a way that it's only called **once** during model construction. In `Layer.add_weight()`:

```py
    if regularizer is not None:
        self.add_loss(regularizer(weight))
```

Once the additional regularization loss tensor is obtained with `regularizer(weight)` and added to the model, the regularizer object itself is useless and got thrown away. So recording epoch (as a `int` or `float`) inside the regularizer object won't work.

If you want a value that can be manipulated during training, you have to make epoch a `Variable`, and include it in the computation of the regularization loss tensor. For example,

```py
epoch_variable = K.variable(0.)

class MyRegularizer(Regularizer):
    def __init__(self, epoch_variable):
        self.epoch_variable = epoch_variable

    def __call__(self, x):
        # just to show that epoch is updated and used in loss computation
        return self.epoch_variable ** 2

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(10,), kernel_regularizer=MyRegularizer(epoch_variable)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

To update the value of `epoch_variable`, use a custom callback:

```py
class MyCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, epoch_variable):
        self.epoch_variable = epoch_variable

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        K.set_value(self.epoch_variable, epoch + 1)

model.fit(X, Y, callbacks=[MyCallback(epoch_variable)])
```

You should see something like:

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 3.0042
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 4.9652
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 9.9544
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 16.7814
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 25.7923
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 36.7659
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 49.7384
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 64.7239
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 81.7514
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 100.7349
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use callbacks, you have access to the epochs, batches and logs for each case.

A [LambdaCallback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback) would be a good option:

```
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback

def epochStart(epoch,logs):
    #do stuff when an epoch starts

    #do stuff with the number of the 'epoch' 
        #(starting from 0, different from the written outputs in your question)

    #do stuff with the logs, which is a dictionary with the 'loss', 'val_loss'    
        #and other metrics you may have used in compile, 
        #such as 'acc', 'val_acc'
        #you may print(logs) to see everything   

def epochEnd(epoch,logs):

    #do stuff when an epoch ends
    #same idea as above


myCallback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=epochStart,on_epoch_end=epochEnd)
```

When training, pass a list of callbacks:

```
model.fit(X,Y,....., callbacks=[myCallback])
```

Comment: This is OK for callbacks but nor for regularizers that have to modify things the gradient depends on.

Comment: I see... my answer really doesn't suit that.